# How to skip resolving dependencies of a specific configuration in Ivy?

Tags: c++, configuration, dependencies, ivy

I have the following problem:

My project (C++) has a dependency to a system library. For that purpose I define in the ivy.xml file a new section within dependencies like this:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="org.acme" module="mymodule">

  <configurations>
    <conf name="system"/>
  </configurations>

  [...]

  <dependencies>
    <dependency name="pthread" rev="*" conf="system"/>
  </dependencies>

</ivy>
```

The problem I am facing is that Ivy tries to resolve the dependency to `pthread` before publishing `mymodule`.

The command use for publishing is the following:

```
java -jar ivy.jar -debug -ivy ivy.xml -publish publish -publishpattern "<ivy-pattern>" -status integration -revision 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -settings ivysettings.xml -overwrite
```

I checked the Ivy documentation but cannot find any hint on how to tell Ivy to skip resolving dependencies for a specific configuration.

Has one of you guys maybe a hint or an idea how to configure that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to exclude the dependency for a specific configuration by using the following dependencies tag:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency name="pthread" rev="*" conf="system"/>
    <exclude conf="system"/>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you please post the ant script used to do publishing?

Comment: I am using ivy.jar for publishing the component. Let me know if you need a full example with ivysettings.xml and ivy.xml

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you must provide ogranisation, module and revision which is needed for [publish task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html). There reason is that if this is not provided `publish` will look for it in last resolved module (check the publish task for the attributes). 
So when you call publish task, it will require either providing all of these attributes, or call to resolve task beforehand. The attributes that are needed are:

- pubrevision
- artifactspattern
- organisation
- module
- revision
- srcivypattern

You can check the link to see which one is what, even thought it's pretty self explanatory.

Now I don't know how(or if at all) you cann pass all these paramaters when calling ivy as a jar. Maybe use `ivyfile` as listed [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html). That's why I gave the answer on how to do it with ant task - well that and because it's usually cleaner and easier to use ivy with ant :)